# Conservation of mass in nuclear reactions

Tags: special-relativity, energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, mass-energy

I've read that the law of conservation of mass doesn't hold in nuclear reactions, but I think it does hold.

Consider the following reaction:
$$\require{mhchem} \ce{ A -> B + C}$$
I can write $m_{A} c^{2}=m_{B} c^{2}+m_C c^{2}$, where $m$ is the relativistic mass of object (not necessarily it's rest mass).

From this equation it follows that $m_{A} =m_{B} +m_{C} $, so the law of conservation of relativistic mass holds. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Imagine there is one electron and one proton that combine into a hydrogen atom. Mass in this process is not conserved, energy on the other hand is conserved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When physicists talk about "mass," then mean rest mass.  So when nuclear reactions are said not to conserve "mass," it is the rest mass that is meant.  The proper way of expressing the energy of a relativistic particle is $E=\gamma mc^{2}$, where $\gamma=(1-v^{2}/c^{2})^{-1/2}$ is the Lorentz factor and $m$ is the rest mass.

In a nuclear reaction $A\rightarrow B+C$, energy $\gamma_{A}m_{A}c^{2}=\gamma_{B}m_{B}c^{2}+\gamma_{C}m_{C}c^{2}$ is conserved, but mass (meaning rest mass) is not, $m_{A}\neq m_{B}+m_{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a fission reaction, splitting of the atomic nucleus A into lighter nuclei B and C will release energy. It's because sum of the rest masses of product nuclei is less than the rest mass of the reactant. That's why mass-energy is conserved instead of only mass.

Also one should keep track of the emitted neutrons. Because this mass difference is recovered by the released energy and emitted high energetic particles like neutrons.

Comment: Thank you, are you talking about rest masses?

Comment: Yes, total rest mass of products is less than the mass of the reactant. This mass difference is recovered by the released energy and high energetic particles like emitted neutrons.

Comment: Imho it'll be better for future readers if you would incorporate that into you answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, fixed it.